# "Penny and I have dinner reservations that night." Why does he use "reservations" rather than "a reservation"?

Tags: plural-forms

In the big bang theory, Leonard says:

> Penny and I have dinner reservations that night.

Why does he use "reservations"? Should he say:

> Penny and I have a dinner reservation that night.

Comment: It's an _idiom_ in English. Either _reservations_ or _reservation_ is normal and natural. There is no grammatical reason for this, other than "because that's the way we say it."

Answer (score 1):

Reservation. One of tne meanings of the word *reservation* is 
an arrangement in which something such as a seat on an aircraft or a table at a restaurant is kept for you, to book  The idiom is used with a singular or plural noun, so you can *make a reservation/reservations*.

> I'd like to make a table reservation for two people for nine o'clock.
>   Please confirm your reservation in writing by Friday.
>   The restaurant is so popular it's almost impossible to get a reservation.
>   Please let us know if you wish to cancel your reservation.
>   The concierge can make dinner or theatre reservations for you.